# Convert RAML Data Types XSD

Tags: xsd, raml

Raml website states that I can convert RAML 1.0 data types to XML Schema:

> Data Types can be used in place of schemas and examples, letting you define one Data Type that can then be converted into an XML or JSON Schema on the fly - letting you simply define your data model, and letting RAML take care of the REST.

How can I do that? And what is the level of support for complex types with inheritance and string patterns?

Answer (score 1):

The statement implies that you can use a XML data type to define a complex structure. This definition is logical and does not specify the physical format like a XML or JSON.

This is a definition of a Album Type:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: AlbumSimple
displayName: Full Album Object
properties:
  artists: ArtistSimple[]  # would pull in ArtistSimple DataType
  copyrights: Copyright[]  # would pull in Copyright DataType
  external_ids: ExternalId  # would pull in ExternalId DataType
  genres:
    type: string[]
    description: |
      A list of the genres used to classify the album. If not yet classified,
      the array is empty.
    example: ["Prog Rock", "Post-Grunge"]
  popularity:
    type: integer
    description: |
      The popularity of the album. The value will be between 0 and 100,
      with 100 being the most popular. The popularity is calculated from
      the popularity of the album's individual tracks.
  tracks:
    type: Page  # would pull in Page DataType
    (pagedObject): TrackSimple
    description: The tracks of the album.
```

That definition does not imply the physical format. You have to define in the body content-type:

```
get:
      is: [ drm ]
      responses:
        201:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: AlbumSimple
```